# Automatically populating simple_form fields - RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Let's say I have a Customer and a Brand class (where a customer has many brands and a brand belongs to a customer). When the user is on the show page for a specific customer, he/she has the option to click a button to add a new brand (that button redirects to the form to create a new brand, which contains a field where the user should indicate which customer that brand belongs to). But when the user gets to that form, he/she should not have to manually indicate which customer that brand belongs to, but rather that information should be entered automatically based on the customer_id of the customer whose show page the user was just looking at. If no show page was being looked at, the field for the parent customer_id should be empty (as it is by default) and the user should enter it manually.

Is there a way to implement this in Rails? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit hard to understand, but let's go.

First, you have to create a link to a new brand, something like:

```
<%= link_to 'New brand for #{@customer.name}", new_brand_path(customer_id: @customer.id) %>
```

In this way you are passing the customer_id as a param.

In the brand controller on the new action you will do

```
def new
    @customer = Customer.find_by_id(params[:customer_id])        
    @brand = @customer ? Brand.new(customer_id: @customer.id) : Brand.new
end
```

You see that I made an example to make it clear what to do. There are better ways of doing that, but I guess this will guide you through what you want.

Comment: The problem with this is that Customer.find will throw an error if it cannot find a record with that id. A safer way would be to do @customer = Customer.find_by(id: params[:customer_id])

Comment: Is there a way I can hide the field from the form if params[:customer_id] is passed over, and only show it if it isn't?

Answer (score 0):

On the link from the show page, you could have something like this

```
<%= link_to 'New Brand', new_brand_path(customer_id: params[:id]) %>
```

Then in the controller, you could have some code that checks to see if the customer_id is present in the params hash in the new action:

```
@brand.customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id]) if params[:customer_id]
```

Now, when the form is rendered, assuming using form_for @brand, the customer field will be set.

If they are linking from another page (other than show), then just don't pass in the customer_id: params[:id] in the link_to method call. It will bypass the if statement in the controller and the customer will be blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @new_brand = @customer.brands.new
```

It populates cusomer_id in @new_brand with correct value